# How to add a new page to the admin view of laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

I have a website in laravel framework and I am trying to add a simple new static page to the admin panel. I have done the following three steps:

Add a template to the views:

```
app/views/admin/MessageToAll.blade.php
```

Add the make view code in the controller.

```
public function MessageToAll(){
return View::make('admin.MessageToAll');
}
```

Added a route in app/routes.php

```
Route::get('/admin/MessageToAll',array('as'=>'MessageToAll','uses'=>'AdminController@MessageToAll'));
```

But when I go to to domain.com/admin/MessageToAll

it gives me a 404 page not found error. Does anyone know what have I missed as I think I have completed all steps for adding this view.

Comment: Which version of Laravel?

Comment: Its laravel version 4

Comment: Do you have a route group with a prefix wrapping that route? What happens if you remove the leading forward slash on the route such as: Route::get('admin/MessageToAll',array('as'=>'MessageToAll','uses'=>'AdminController@MessageToAll'));

Comment: No I don't have  a prefix wrapping the routes. My other urls with the pattern are working perfectly fine like my view dashboard route:
Route::get('/admin/',array('as'=>'viewDashboard','uses'=>'AdminControl‌​ler@viewDashboard')); 
is working fine. The problem is with this one Message To All only

Comment: Double check the order of your routes. It could be that route is being prematurely matched.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your new route before the `/admin/` route (to test it, you want to temporarily make it the very first route in `routes.php`). The problem is `/admin/` or some other similar route executed before your new route.

Also, if you need to just execute static view, you can use something like this (works without using a controller):

```
Route::get('/admin/MessageToAll', function (){
    return View::make('admin.MessageToAll');
});
```

Comment: Both of your solutions are not working, giving a 404 error not found

Comment: Please update your post with full contents of `routes.php`

Answer (score 0):

in routes add:
Route::get('/admin/MessageToAll','yourController@yourMethod');

Comment: No luck with this one as well, getting a 404 page not found

Comment: please create page 'MessageToAll.blade.php' in resources/view/admin directory